# How can I get the process filename under Vista?

Tags: winapi, windows-vista

I have an application that aids people with disabilities. In order to work, it tracks the what window is currently in the foreground. Normally, I use this function to get process executable.

```
bool GetWindowProcessExe2(HWND hwnd, wxString& process_exe)  
                       //LPTSTR buf, DWORD size)
{
DWORD result = 0;
DWORD pid = 0;
GetWindowThreadProcessId(hwnd, &pid);
if (HANDLE process =
    OpenProcess(PROCESS_ALL_ACCESS, FALSE, pid))
{
  char buff[512];
  LPTSTR pbuff = buff;
  result = GetModuleFileNameEx(process, 0, pbuff, 512);
  if(result == 0)
  {
    //failed.
    wxLogError("GetModuleFileNameEx failed with error code %d", GetLastError());
  }
  CloseHandle(process);
  process_exe = fromCString(pbuff);
}

return result > 0 ? true : false;
```

}

Unfortunately, if the foreground window is the Vista file manager window (the window that opens when you click Start->Computer), `GetModuleFileNameEx()` fails with error code 299 which says I don't have privileges for this action. My code works for any regular application but not for the windows built in window (the file explorer). I need to know when this window is forefront. Is there another way to do it? I tried reading the window title but that just returns the current directory being shown. Any ideas?

Comment: had same issue, use [`GetProcessImageFileName`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms683217(v=vs.85).aspx) instead

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure why this isn't working for explorer, but error 299 is `ERROR_PARTIAL_COPY`, meaning that attempting to read the module name out of explorer is failing.

On Vista, prefer `QueryProcessImageFileName` and only open the process with `PROCESS_QUERY_LIMITED_INFORMATION` - your code will work in more cases.

```
WCHAR exeName[512];
DWORD cchExeName = 512;
HANDLE process = OpenProcess(PROCESS_QUERY_LIMITED_INFORMATION, 0, pid);
QueryFullProcessImageName(process, 0, exeName, &cchExeName);
```

EDIT: I also got `ERROR_PARTIAL_COPY` with your code running on 64-bit, but only when the querying process was 32-bit.  64-bit/64-bit worked fine.

Comment: Thanks for the help; I appreciate it! I'm having trouble linking the code snippet. I get a linker error: LNK2019 unresolved external, symbol __imp__QueryFullProcessImageNameA@16 referenced in function .... I've included kernel32.lib. I'm developing on vista 64, if it matters. I'm using psdk 2003.

Comment: QueryFullProcessImageName wouldn't be in the 2003 SDK since it was introduced with Vista.  If updating your SDK isn't an option, you can use LoadLibrary/GetProcAddress to get QueryFullProcessImageName.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like a 32 bit process can call GetModuleFileNameEx only on othere 32 bit processes. If you try to call it on 64 bit processes it fails with ERROR_PARTIAL_COPY.On a 64 bit platform make the calling process 64 bit and you should be able to call GetModuleFileNameEx on both 64 and 32 bit processes.